# I cannot open Memory window in Visual Studio Community Version

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I enabled "source level debugging" and even "Show disassembly if source is not available" in Options>Debugging. But it just doesnt help. What am I doing wrong.

Platform: Windows 7 x64 Edition 
[image: System Information]

Enabled Address Level Debugging
[image: Address Level Debugging Enabled]
VS info
[image: VS Info]
Debug Window Menu:
[image: Debug menu(Updated)]

**Code for main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SFmqpapi.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    if (true) {
        MPQHANDLE mpq=(MPQHANDLE *)malloc(sizeof(MPQHANDLE));
        if (SFileOpenArchive("./Map.w3x", 1, 0, &mpq)) {
            MPQHANDLE fp;
            if (SFileOpenFileEx(mpq, "war3map.j", 0, &fp)) {
                MPQFILE *fle;
                char* out;
                out = (char*)malloc(2996801);
                SFileReadFile(fp, out, 2996801, NULL,NULL);
                cout << "Yay Opened!"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "No map specified!" << endl;
    }

}
```

What is wrong with this configuration? or It is not supported in Visual Studio Community at all ? 
I am currently using cheat engine for that. Is there any better alternative If VSCommunity doesnt support it ?

Comment: Is this the entire "Debug->Windows" menu? It seems that it's been cut-off.

Comment: default shortcut is `Alt+6` so maybe try that if you can't find it in the UI or the Quick Launch

Comment: yes it is but still there you go. http://prntscr.com/l8yb9u

Comment: Alt+6 doesnt open anything, but it does make mouse pointer blink though.

Comment: There should be `Memory` item just below Processes item in that menu. Are you sure you are debugging C++ code and not something like C# or C++/cli?

Comment: In addition, When I tried searching Memory in QL it shows me this https://prnt.sc/l8yfzj

Comment: @VTT Yes this is authentic C++ code as per my beliefs, Code has been added for explanation.

Comment: the "live visual tree" and "live property explorer" options should only be there if you're debugging C# or C++/CLI code, try to compile and run native C++ or try to set the debugger mode to "Native Only"

Comment: @PeterT I have already make debugger mode to "Native Only"(and all others) before asking this question on this site, I know your time is precious and It will really help me if I can do this. Can debugging with "Local Windows Debugger" cause this? Do I need another debugger?

Comment: If this happens with every application, even if you attach to a native app then I'd say try to reinstall VSCommunity and update it to the newest version. It's definately supported in that version and I've used it.

Comment: It does happen in every executable I debug(2 real projects, 5 dummies with different scenario and attach to process feature) but still wasnt able to make it work. I will reinstall VS Community right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think your VS installation misses components.
I'm not 100% sure but I think it's "Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package".